# Por que fonte não é alterada na Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gtk, gtk-python

Tenho uma aplicação gráfica utilizando Gtk em Python, o programa tem definições de fontes e tamanhos de fontes. Ao executar o programa no linux funciona corretamente, mas ao executar na Raspberry a fonte não é alterada. Alguém sabe o por que isso acontece?

A parte do código que modifica a fonte é a seguinte:

```
self.tp_encerrar_btn.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription('Dejavu Sans 10'))
```

Ou dessa forma, para modificar somente o tamanho e deixar a fonte padrão:

```
fonte = Pango.FontDescription()
fonte.set_absolute_size(15000)
self.tp_tabela.modify_font(fonte)
```

Verifiquei os pacotes instalados no linux mint e instalei todos na Raspberry, modifiquei a fonte com diversos nomes diferentes mas nenhuma funciona, copiei as fontes do linux mint e coloquei na Raspberry e também não funcionou.
Verifiquei também as fontes instaladas na Raspberry, e estão todas as que tentei instaladas. Não está parecendo lógico esse erro, o mais interessante é que se modificar somente o tamanho da fonte, deixando a fonte padrão, o tamanho também não é alterado. Existe alguma possível explicação e solução para esse caso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema parece mais complicado do que deveria ser.

Aparentemente um dos desenvolvedores da UI do Raspberry decidiu que não é pras pessoas ficarem trocando fontes - veja essa postagem aqui:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1070816#p1070816

E ela é referenciada por pessoas que tiveram o mesmo problema que você está tendo (embora programando em C).

Elas conseguiram contornar o problema - mas o código para forçar outra fonte fica bem mais complicado, sendo necessário usar os mecanismos internos de CSS do Gtk3 - acomanhe a thread abaixo e veja a postagem de 29 de novembro de 2016 do PeterO:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=166690

Uma variação do programa usando gtk + CSS que funciona em Python no computador é:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk, Gdk as gdk

import tempfile, os


def setup():
    window = gtk.Window()

    # Aqui onde perdi mais tempo: nos exemplos usando glade, os
    # seletores parecem ser "GtkTextView" e "GtkButton" - 
    # mas sem o glade são "textview" e "button" em minúsculas.
    # (Também pode ser diferença na versão do GTK)
    css = "textview {font-size: 24pt; color: #d0d0ff;}\n button {font-size: 40pt; color: #ff0000} "
    # (a cor do textview não funcionou ) 


    provider = gtk.CssProvider()
    css_filename = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile().name
    with open(css_filename, "wt") as css_file:
        css_file.write(css)
    provider.load_from_path(css_filename)
    # Existe o método "load_from_data", que no exemplo em C
    # carrega uma string direto - mas em Python esse método
    # não está funcionando, por isso o arquivo temporário

    print(css_filename, provider.to_string())
    # esse print certifica que o CSS foi lido e parseado: 
    # o GTK muda a formatação do whitespace

    os.remove(css_filename)

    frame = gtk.VBox()
    window.add(frame)

    text = gtk.TextView()
    text.set_name("texto")
    frame.pack_start(text, True, True, 6)
    button = gtk.Button("Text test")
    button.set_name("botao")

    frame.pack_start(button, False, True, 6)

    # aplica-se a styleshhet a toda a aplicação,
    # em vez de um único widget. 

    screen = gdk.Screen.get_default()
    context = gtk.StyleContext()
    context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, provider, gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)

    window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    window.show_all()



def main():
    gtk.init([])
    window = setup()
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: Agora está explicado, não fazia sentido nenhum isso. Muito Obrigado pela resposta! Como poderia fazer aquele código em Python? Se eu conseguir aumentar a fonte já está ótimo!

Comment: Não dá para acreditar, consegui fazer aqui no computador, mas também não gera mudanças na Raspberry!

Comment: hmmm... fiz no computador aqui - compare com o seu. Acertar os seletores deu algum trabalho, já que são diferentes do exemplo lá.

Comment: No computador ocorre as mudanças mas na Raspberry não! Já estou cansado, a 2 dias em cima disso e não saio do lugar. Muito obrigado pela tentativa. Será que existe alguma outra possibilidade?

Comment: daqui: achoque fazer pergutnas em um forum em ingles, sobre raspbery mesmo, sem se preocupar com a linguagem - foque em GTK e querer mudar as fontes. E .. tentar mudar os seletores do CSS. Pode ser que mudem de uma versão pra outra do gtk e seja diferente no que roda no rasp.