# Como desabilitar o cursor de texto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk-python

Tenho um projeto em Gtk, que utiliza uma entrada de texto Gtk.Entry e preciso desabilitar o cursor de texto, ou deixa-lo invisível. Como posso fazer isso? Ou caso não consiga, tem como desabilitar o cursor do sistema linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é possível -

Na documentação não há nenhum método relacionado a isso.
E, embora o GTK3+ suporte a configuração de estilo por CSS, algumas tentativas que fiz aqui não modificaram o cursor.

Em particular, tentei selecionar o cursor  com a classe ".insert-cursor" e varia scombinações dentre nome do elemento e nome de classe entre "cursos-handle" e "insert-cursor", conforme as dicas aqui: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-get-cursor-hadjustment

Para alterar o CSS tentei usar o CSS global do aplicativo, apenas modificando a prova de conceito que fiz pra essa resposta aqui:
[Por que fonte não é alterada na Raspberry Pi?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274718/por-que-fonte-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-alterada-na-raspberry-pi/274856#274856)

Não consegui nem mudar a cor - se funcionasse a cor, aí tentaria setar o "opacity" pra 0, tendo em vista que "display" e "width" não funcionam de qualquer forma (ele dá erro e para o programa ao fazer o parse do CSS)